# oracle pragma SERIALLY_REUSABLE, RESTRICT_REFERENCES and INLINE

Tags: oracle, postgresql, pragma

Recently moved to db migration project where we have to migrate code from oracle database to postgres database.In oracle we have pragma SERIALLY_REUSABLE, RESTRICT_REFERENCES and INLINE, i want to know how to implement these functionalities in postgresql??

Comment: What do these thing do? Where do you specify them? And which problem are they solving for you?

Comment: Right. You will get better answers if you don't force us to read Oracle documentation.

Comment: In oracle , there is pragma restrict_references() to restrict the DML operations against any of database tables(WNDS) , select query is restricted against any of database tables(RNDS).... how to implement these functionalities in Postgresql??

Answer (score 2):

The `RESTRICT_REFERENCES` pragma is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/RESTRICT_REFERENCES-pragma.html). Oracle recommends using the `DETERMINISTIC` option instead. The `DETERMINISTIC` option implies `RESTRICT_REFERENCES(fun1, WNDS, WNPS)` pragma, and that the function returns the same results on two distinct invocations if the arguments provided to the two invocations are the same.

The `DETERMINISTIC` option in Oracle:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun1(...) RETURN type1 DETERMINISTIC AS <body>
```

is equivalent to the `IMMUTABLE` option in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun1(...) RETURNS type1 AS $$ <body> $$ LANGUAGE plpgql IMMUTABLE;
```